# What is the mechanism for multiply layers implementation in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to figure out how to implement multiply layers effect in HTML5 canvas. I created a project [xboxp.com](http://xboxp.com) to implement a html5 chart. I use two canvas to implement a tooltip effect. How to achieve this in only one canvas? What is the mechanism for implementation? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general mechanism for using html canvas in any project is to save enough information about individual drawings so they can be redrawn as needed. This information is often stored in javascript objects.

When a change is desired on the canvas (eg, showing a tooltip):

- Clear the canvas.
- Redraw the drawings in their currently desired position.

So, to use 1 canvas to implement your tooltips:

- When you need a tooltip you must draw the tooltip over the chart.
- Then when the tooltip is no longer needed you must clear the canvas and redraw the chart without the tooltip.

Comment: So, it is just like animation frame. I wonder how to implement it? Is there any code sample?

Comment: Yes, canvas can be like animation frames: draw, clear, redraw next, clear, redraw next, etc.  Your own design determines what your tooltip looks like--just draw the tooltip on top of your chart when you need it.